# How to open the file system of a volume in CreateFile?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, runtime-error, createfile

The MSDN page on CreateFile says: The string `"\\.\C:\"` can be used to open the file system of the C: volume. However, the following code always returns an error : ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND.

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:\\", FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

How should I pass the arguments correctly?

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting handle?

Comment: I just wonder why it didn't work as expected. My initial intent was to list files under the root directory.

Comment: in my case, I get INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted a volume handle (for use with I/O control codes) you would have needed to drop the trailing slash.

In order to get a handle to the root directory, you need to keep the trailing slash and pass the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag in the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` argument.  This is documented on the MSDN page under the heading "Directories".  For example, this is what you want to do if you're planning to call `GetFileInformationByHandle` or `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`.

Ordinarily, however, you wouldn't open a handle to the root directory in order to list the files.  Instead, you would use `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` or one of the related functions.

Comment: Why does this work? C: isn't defined in the device namespace. Surely you'd have to use `L"\\??\\C:"`

Comment: @Lewis, I've never found any documentation that clearly explains the way the device namespace works, but see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/884359/96662) on Super User.  C: is an alias in `GLOBAL??` as can be confirmed using WinObj.

Comment: that's interesting, maybe it searches both global and the device namespace. I will have to look at the source code of the object manager function that does it I think

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the trailing slash:

```
L"\\\\.\\C:"
```

Comment: I think you misconstrued what I mean. I know it will be OK if the trailing backslash is dropped. However, although the documentation explicitly declares the trailing backslash is a valid argument, CreateFile always returns an error. That's the key point of my question.